# Management of retrieved dataTable columns

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-2

I have 13 columns in a table. When I display it in a `<h:dataTable>`, then it expands to a very wide area on the page.

Is there any way to minimize their width or to display some columns above and some columns below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `h:dataTable`'s `columnClasses` attribute to set width of columns.

From the [Java EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnaqz/index.html):

> If columnClasses or rowClasses
>   specifies more than one style, the
>   styles are applied to the columns or
>   rows in the order that the styles are
>   listed in the attribute. For example,
>   if columnClasses specifies styles
>   list-column-center and
>   list-column-right and if the table has
>   two columns, the first column will
>   have style list-column-center, and the
>   second column will have style
>   list-column-right.

You can define styles for different widths and assign these styles to your columns. Here is an example:

```
<h:dataTable id="items"
    columnClasses="list-column-center, list-column-left,
         list-column-right, list-column-center">
  ...
</h:dataTable>
```

And in your css file:

```
.list-column-center{ width: 300px; }
.list-column-left{ width: 100px; }
```

If you want to display columns in rows you can use for example two datatables in a panelGrid:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1">
  <h:dataTable value=#{myBean.myTable} var="item">
    <h:column>#{item.column1}</h:column>
    ...
  </h:dataTable>
  <h:dataTable value=#{myBean.myTable} var="item">
    <h:column>#{item.column2}</h:column>
    ...
  </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```